# C# Sorting lines by score

Tags: c#, winforms

I have class called Player, which has properties name and score, and after every game they are written in file with method `File.AppendAllText(path, content+Environment.NewLine);` .
And now I have to add them to listBox when label "Scores" is clicked and new Form is loaded..but I would like to use my class Player, and add items to list or something as players and not just load them from file...I used `SortedList`  as shown below...

```
    SortedList<int, Player> topList = new SortedList<int, Player>();

    private void Scores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        topList.Clear();
        string filename = "highscores.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] s = line.Split(';');
                string name = s[0];
                int score = int.Parse(s[1]);
                Player newPlayer = new Player(name, score);
                if (!topList.ContainsKey(score))
                    topList.Add(score, newPlayer);
            }
        }

        Output();
    }
    private void Output()
    {
        lstScores.Items.Clear();
        int rank = 1;
        foreach (int k in topList.Keys.Reverse())
        {
            if (rank < 10)//top 9
            {
                Player temp = (Player)topList[k];
                lstScores.Items.Add("  " + rank.ToString() + "\t" + temp.ToString());//override of method ToString(), so it returns in format Name+"\t"+Score;
            }
            rank++;
        }
    }
```

Now this is acceptable, but problem here is that I can't have two same keys, in this case key is score...so I want to know how can I modify this so I can have two or more same scores?....Maybe I should use `List<>`, but I don't know how to sort that list by scores because I have string + int in same line of file (name + score) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use List:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
players.Add(new Player(name, score));
```

And to sort it by score:

```
var sorted = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).ToList();
```

Comment: Looks like you store and sort scores as strings.
You can sort by int values:
var sorted = players.OrderBy(p => Int32.Parse(p.Score)).ToList();

Comment: Still doesn't work somehow, but nevermind, I only needed 10th place, so I added if statement which inserts that 10th player on index 9, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Read your file and yield players, then use the Link OrderBy operator:

```
private IEnumerable<Player> ReadPlayers(TextReader rd){
  string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] s = line.Split(';');
            string name = s[0];
            int score = int.Parse(s[1]);
            yield return new Player(name, score);
        }
}

private void Scores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = "highscores.txt";
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename)){ 
      var sortedPlayers= ReadPlayers(rd)
                             .OrderByDescending(x=x.Score)
                             .Take(10)
                             .Select((p,r)=>$"rank {r+1}:{p.Name} : {p.Score}");
       lstScore.Items.Clear();
       foreach(var p in sortedPlayers) lstScore.Items.Add(p); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *List* instead of a *SortedList* and use the *OrderBy* Linq method (System.Linq):

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

var topList = new List<Player>();
topList = topList.OrderBy(x => x.Score);
```